# How to access member function without using the member.functionName syntax c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, member-functions

I am trying to access a member function of my Fraction class called "compare" which takes 2 parameters, both Fraction objects. Why is it that the only way I can call the compare function is through a member of the Fraction class? For example, I have the following code:

```
bool operator==(Fraction a, Fraction b) {
    if (compare(a, b) < 0) {  // this line gives an error during compilation
        // Do stuff
    }
    return true;
}

int Fraction::compare(Fraction a, Fraction b) {
    // do stuff
    return 0;
}
```

The error given at the line where compare is called, and it gives the following message:

> ..\fraction.cpp:107:18: error: 'compare' was not declared in this scope

If I change that line to the following, it works.

```
if (a.compare(a, b) < 0) {
```

It seems redundant that the only way to call compare is by doing `a.compare`, when a is an input parameter to the function anyway. I understand I can get out of this by making the operator overload function a friend function but I am being asked to implement it as a non-member function.

Is there a way to make this function `static` like in Java where I can just call `Fraction.compare(a, b)`, or is this not possible in C++11?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: you can make compare a static member function and call it Fraction::compare(a,b)

Comment: What's your question? `compare` is a non-static member function, when you call it in a non-member function you need a instance to call on it. You want to change it to non-member function? Or static member function? Or sth else?

Comment: So you know the name of what you're looking for: a static member function. What's the obstacle here, why do you need help figuring out the syntax?

Comment: @Cimbali yeah it was a syntax issue. I was used to Java where you access static members through the dot operator, and when I tried that in C++ it gave very vague suggestions. All good now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could declare the method static and access it through [operator `::`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator)
Ex:

```
class Fraction {
public:
    static bool compare(int a, int b);
};

bool Fraction::compare(int a, int b)
{
    return a > b;
}

int main()
{
    cout << boolalpha << Fraction::compare(5, 4) << '\n';
}
```